# Trying to get the cell value of the tr element

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer

I am trying to get the value of the first `<tr>` cell present in the HTML. I am using the following code `elem[0]` contains that HTML file.

When I am debugging through the browser console, the `tHead` element contains the `<tr>` element.

When I am trying to get the length of it, the return value is zero. And also when I am accessing `scope.table.tHead.rows[0].cells` for getting the cell value present in `<tr>`, I am getting the below error message.

This is happening only in IE 11 Edge.

Can you please help me? What may be the issue? The error message is:

> Unable to get property 'cells' of undefined or null reference  scope.table = elem[0];
>      var headers = scope.table.tHead.rows[0].cells;
>     Browser: IE 11 Edge  Version: 11.0.9600.18230  Update Versions: 11.0.29

Comment: A better question is "Why are you trying to locate DOM elements in AngularJS?" Perform whatever change you are trying to do to the cell with a Directive. Read/write whatever value you are trying to read/write through the Model.

Comment: I am implementing a new feature drag and drop of columns. Columns will be dynamically generated and it is retrieved from db in the form of some id - number like eps-01. I am assuming those value as id for that th element. When the user is trying to drag and drop, we have to fetch the current order like eps-01 here, 01 is the order. When I start drag and drop on other all th elements ID has to be updated and send to DB. I am performing that particular inside a directive only..